# Prove that a must be $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Original version of the question:**

If the sum $ \sum\limits_{f(a)}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(g(n)(n^{-a}-n^{a-1})=0 $ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(g(n)$ is divergent then prove that a=0.5 .

---

**Edit:** *(@Did) The question above is ambiguous, and might be referring to statements A or B below.*

A. Prove the following:

> Let $a$ denote a real number. Assume that, for every divergent series $\sum\limits_{n}g(n)$, the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty g(n)(n^{-a}-n^{a-1})$ converges and its sum is $0$. Then $a=0.5$.

B. Prove the following:

> Let $a$ denote a real number and $\sum\limits_{n}g(n)$ a divergent series. Assume that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty g(n)(n^{-a}-n^{a-1})$ converges and that its sum is $0$. Then $a=0.5$.

Comment: The initial $\sum_{f(a)}$ must be a typo...?

Comment: It only implies summation is as function of a

Comment: This isn't the notation you're looking for.

Comment: It is any function such as f(x)=0

Comment: Added two reformulations of the question, please indicate which one is the question you meant to ask. (Caveat: be aware that the answer to the first version is obvious, and that the second version is obviously false.)

Comment: @Did I meant the second.Can you please elaborate why answer to second is false because if a=0.5 the sum of series will be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version B is false. To see why, define $g_c(2)=\frac12+c$ and $g_c(n)=\frac1n$ for every $n\geqslant2$, for some $c$. Then the series $\sum\limits_ng_c(n)$ diverges and, for every $a$ in $(0,1)$, the series $\sum\limits_ng_c(n)(n^{-a}-n^{a-1})$ converges and its sum $G_c$ is
$$
G_c=c\,(2^{-a}-2^{a-1})+\sum_{n\geqslant1}(n^{-a-1}-n^{a-2})=c\,(2^{-a}-2^{a-1})+\zeta(a+1)-\zeta(2-a).
$$
If $a=\frac12$, $G_c=0$ for every $c$. If $a\ne\frac12$, $G_c=0$ if $c=c(a)$, where
$$
c(a)=\frac{\zeta(a+1)-\zeta(2-a)}{2^{a-1}-2^{-a}},
$$
hence every $g_{c(a)}$ with $a\ne\frac12$ in $(0,1)$ is a counterexample.